# React Cannot destructure property 'params' of 'this.props.match' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a route set up to render the details for an individual item but its throwing an error saying 'this.props.match' is undefined. Hence cant deconstruct

Here is my code snippet

```
class ProfilesSinglePage extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)

        this.state={
            details:''
        };
    }
    render(){
        console.log(this.props);
        const {params} = this.props.match;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Profiles Details for id {params.id}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
        axios.get(`${Profiles}/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({details:res.data})
        });
    };
};
```

Here is how the route looks like

```
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/profiles" exact element={<ProfilesAllPage/>}/>
        <Route path="/profile-details/:id" exact element={<ProfileSinglePage/>}/>
      </Routes>
```

Comment: So what does `console.log(this.props)` yield?

Comment: The problem is a missing prop, so we don't actually need to know about this component as much as we need to know about how it is used. What does the `Route` look like? Are you using the `withRouter` HOC?

Comment: @BrianThompson I didn't quite catch you what do you mean by HOC but i edited the question on how the routes look like

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using react v6 version hence to get access to params you need to import useParams from react-router-dom and then create a hook to access the URL parameters.

for a better understanding visit-
https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-get-query-and-url-parameters/#reading-url-parameters